# Is there a way to programmatically show all gmail labels in IMAP?

Tags: .net, gmail, google-apps, label, gmail-imap

Assuming I have access to the user's account, and an administrator account on the domain, is there a way to enable the all of the labels in IMAP (to be more precise "showing" them in IMAP under the Labels).

I've looked through the google api [here](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.htm), but you can only [change IMAP settings (On/Off)](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_imap_main).

Note: If it is necessary, the user could provide the password for their accounts.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, There is no programmatic method to toggle the show/hide in IMAP setting of a label.